# DAO design and implement practice

Tags: java, hibernate, dao, genericdao, hibernate-generic-dao

For example, I have many tables, such as `people` `car` `house` and so forth, I want to know a good practice for the general DAO design.

In this case, `people` have `cars` and `houses`. `car` and `house` have it own id, maybe an auto_increment int value. and they also have a foreign key `userId` which is the PK of the `user`.

First step, I design a `GenericDao` to provide basic CRUD function for all tables.

And then?

I need to find all cars for user A, so I need a `CarDao` with function `findAllCarsForUser(int userid)`, which may also have `findCarsByName(String name)` and `findCarsByNameForUser(String name, int userid)` and so on.
For `House`, a same `HouseDao` is needed. If the people have other type of things, each should have an `ObjectXXXDao`.

But for the upper layer, should the `XXXDao` exposed to them?

I think it should not, so every `DAO` have a wrapped `Service` class, such as `CarService` `HouseService` and so on. But for functions in these service class, maybe only statement `return XXXDao.findCarsByNameForUser()`. nothing or little additional function is added to the service classes.

Or what function should be added to this `XXXservice` layer?

And If there are requirements to join the `Car` and `House` table, maybe a `CarHouseDao` and `CarHouseService` is needed.

I want to know, Is this a good design for a common DAO? If not, is there any good advice or examples?

Comment: maybe read about [aggregate roots](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) in DDD.

Comment: If your service do nothing other than calling DAO methods, they're pretty much redundant. The idea of a service layer is to implement the functional use cases of the application. Like for example "user buys a car", which consists in deleting the user's old car, change the owner of the bought car, decrease the user's amount of money, etc. A single service method will thus use several DAOs.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your answer, Is there any good examples for me? Is it good for every object to have a `ObjectDao` and a `ObjectService`?  I also understand your example, but in actually, there must be some basic service, which only call the dao and do nothing. In this case, should I call the `ObjectDao` directly and discard the `ObjectService` class?

Comment: Check these to understand  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049609/call-service-vs-dao-from-another-service/32049986#32049986 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882108/dao-and-service-layers-jpa-hibernate-spring?rq=1